# Как в numpy изменить массив

Tags: python, numpy

Есть numpy массив вида

```
L = np.array(['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c'])
```

Как с помощью numpy этот массив видоизменить в:

```
[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
```

Там есть метод:

```
np.where(L == 'a', 1, 2)
```

но он заменит все что "а" на 1 а все остальные на 2, а нужно что бы для каждого вида данных в массиве была своя цифра.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [73]: categories, indices = np.unique(L, return_inverse=True)

In [74]: indices
Out[74]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int64)

In [75]: indices + 1
Out[75]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], dtype=int64)

In [76]: categories
Out[76]:
array(['a', 'b', 'c'],
      dtype='<U1')
```

еще можно воспользоваться Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

In [81]: ser = pd.Series(L)

In [82]: ser
Out[82]:
0     a
1     a
2     a
3     a
4     b
     ..
7     b
8     c
9     c
10    c
11    c
Length: 12, dtype: object

In [83]: indices = pd.factorize(ser)[0] + 1

In [84]: indices
Out[84]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: как всегда идеально, спс

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч, спасибо :)